# Export results to a txt file

Tags: php, xml

I coded something to export data from an xml into a txt:

For example, the xml display keywords between multiple `<screenname>` tags.

Then, it creates a txt one keyword per line like this:

```
keyword1
keyword2
etc...
```

Here is the code I made:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("thexml.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $screenname) {
$nick =  $screenname->screenname;
file_put_contents('online.txt',$nick . "\n",FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

The problem is I want to overwrite the `online.txt` each time I run the script. If I delete `FILE_APPEND` from the script, it just outputs the first result. If I run the script with `FILE_APPEND`, it just adds more keyword to the last txt created each time I run the script.

Comment: You need to improve your logic, delete the file first then in your look keep appending the keywords.

Comment: You append inside the loop. If you create inside the loop, the file will only contain the last entry. That's just a little typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to create a new file every run. Just open it with w+, this will start the pointer at the first position and overwrite/delete the contents.

```
$file = fopen('online.txt', 'w+');

$xml=simplexml_load_file("thexml.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $screenname) 
  {
    $nick =  $screenname->screenname;
    fwrite($file, $nick.PHP_EOL);
  }
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an if statement within the loop to turn file_append on/off:

```
<?php
  $xml=simplexml_load_file("thexml.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
  $new_file = True
  foreach($xml->children() as $screenname) {
    $nick =  $screenname->screenname;
    if ($new_file) {
       file_put_contents('online.txt',$nick . "\n");
       $new_file = False;
    } else {
       file_put_contents('online.txt',$nick . "\n",FILE_APPEND);
    }
  }
?>
```